# Confusion on the paper "Cohomology of maximal ideal space"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

In the paper [Cohomology of Maximal Ideal Space](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-67/issue-5/Cohomology-of-maximal-ideal-spaces/bams/1183524331.full), there is a corollary about if $M$ is a compact orientable n-dimensional manifold, then $C(M,\mathbb{C})$ cannot be generated by fewer than n+1 elements.

I am confused by that, consider $S^{1}$, it is only generated by 1 elements only,namely $e^{i\theta}$. Is the definition of "generator" different in this context?

Comment: Don't you also need $e^{-i\theta}$?

Comment: Usually(at least for me), I said the *-algebra generated by n elements means the elements are polynomials of n generators and their adjoint. But I guess I figure out what is the confusion.

Comment: Their notion of "generated" is explained in the first paragraph of the paper: they only look at polynomials in the generators, without the adjoints.